# How to keep the user logged on the entire web

Tags: php, session, cookies, authentication

I have a problem logging users. When logs, session work, but when you click to another page, the session will disappear and does not work and when I put session_start to the main page and to login.php, I got error that session is already running. Some ideas? Thanks

Main Page.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
        <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">
        <title>----</title>
    </head>
<body>

    <!-- HEADER      _____________________________________________________________________________ --                        >
<div id="whiteblock">
    <div id="grayblock">
        <div id="logo">
        </div>
            <h1>----</h1>
            <h2>----</h2>

            <a href="websiteregister.php" id="registration">Registration</a>

                <?php 
                    include "Login.php"; 
                    echo $_SESSION["LogiNick"];
                ?> 

                <div id="inputposunuti">
                    <form name="Log" id="Log" method="post">
                        <label for="Nick" class="inputtext">Nick:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="LogiNick" id="LogiNick" class="input"> <?php echo $EmptyNick; echo $Else; ?>

                        <label for="Pass" class="inputtext">Password:</label>
                        <input type="password" name="LogiPass" id="LogiPass" class="input"> <?php echo $EmptyPass; echo $Else; ?>

                        <input type="submit" name="LogIn" value="⇒">
                    </form>

    </div>      
</div>
<!-- HEADER _____________________________________________________________________________ -->

<!-- MENU _______________________________________________________________________________ -->

<div id="pruh">
    <div id="search">
        <form name="search" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="hledat" id="sirka">
            <input type="submit" name="subhledat" value="Search!" id="button">
        </form>
    </div>
        <div id="menutext">
            <a href="website.php"> <p>Home</p> </a>
            <a href="#"> <p>----</p> </a>
            <a href="#"> <p>----</p> </a>
            <a href="#"> <p>----</p> </a>
            <a href="#"> <p>----</p> </a>
            <a href="#"> <p>----</p> </a>
        </div>
</div>

<!-- MENU _______________________________________________________________________________ -->

<!-- CONTENT ____________________________________________________________________________ -->

<!-- CONTENT ____________________________________________________________________________ -->

<div id="teams"></div>
</div>


<p id="creator">Created by</p>
```

Login.php

```
<?php
    session_start();

    include_once "db.php";
    global $db;

        $Else = $EmptyNick = $EmptyPass = $EmptyNick = "";

            if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

                $LogiNick = $_POST["LogiNick"];
                $LogiPass = $_POST["LogiPass"];

                if (empty($_POST["LogiNick"])) {
                    $EmptyNick = " - Nick";
                }
                if (empty($_POST["LogiPass"])) {
                    $EmptyPass = " - Password";
                }


            }

            if(!empty($_POST["LogiNick"]) AND !empty($_POST["LogiPass"])){

                $LogiPass = $_POST["LogiPass"];
                $SHA = sha1($LogiPass);

                $sql = "SELECT * FROM WEB_REGISTER WHERE Nick = :nick AND Heslo = :heslo";
                $query = $db->prepare($sql);
                $query->execute(array('nick' => $LogiNick, 'heslo' => $SHA));

                    $count = $query->rowCount();

                    if ($count > 0) {
                        $_SESSION["LogiNick"];
                    }
            }
?>
```

Comment: look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php, also sanitize user input, you code looks vulnerable to SQL injection to me

Comment: *"on the entire web"* - Huh? You mean more like *"on the entire website"*, right?

Comment: You also have a bunch of *commented-out* code, why? and did you start the session and in all files using sessions? I hope I'm not typing all this for nothing. Questioners like these tend to ignore comments and just have people pop in a magic answer.

Comment: Yep, I was right on the ball with this one.

Comment: ^^ yep you are right, once again haha

Comment: Yes, I started in all. Now, I did somethink and it works. Thanks for your time

Comment: @Kiro alsto take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php this can save you a lot of trouble ^^

Comment: There was *zero effort* put into this question/problem. Had you spent the better part of what.... 20 minutes (to Google/try something), you'd of solved it yourself and have **learned** from it. **You're the one** who would **benefit** it from it, instead of someone **throwing you a fish** rather than you **learning HOW to fish**; think about it ;-)

Comment: @Fred -ii- : good points, but they will never reach the people who should think about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just set a session if you put a value into it.

```
$_SESSION["name"]=$value;
```